# Gui builder editing in netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans-7

I am trying to use the gui builder in Netbeans 7.3 to build an shopping cart application.
In that i want a dropdown list of different categories but when i change their default value .They are not appearing on editing.

I placed a jList on the Panel, their values was Item 1,Item 2,Item 3, Item 4, Item 5 by default, to change them

- I right-clicked and selected customize code .
- I then clicked on default code button changed it to customize code.
- I changed item 1 to apple, it did not appear on jList .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the GUI builder changing your code? Note: many of us, myself included aren't big fans of GUI editors.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I tend to disagree. The GUI builder in NetBeans is actually pretty good and allows you full control over the generated code. And it's the best way to understand GridBagLayout ;) - But from the question it's absolutely unclear where Siva's problem is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that's why I said "many" and not "all". But even most of my friends who like and use Matisse agree that a user is better off learning and understanding the rudiments of Swing before using the tool.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).